# How to convert <textarea> output to clean html and write to file?

Tags: php

My script writes content of < textarea > to text file:

```
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html &lt;?php language_attributes(); ?&gt;&gt;
&lt;head&gt; etc
```

Is there anyway I can convert output to clean html so it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
```

etc :)

```
$file = 'wp.txt';
$regex = '/<textarea name="example" id="newcontent">(.*?)<\/textarea>/s';
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
echo $list[0];
else
print "Error";

$file = 'wp.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $list, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't like the answers could you give a better explanation.

Comment: I'm not marking answers as not useful and I do not know who is doing it. Always appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html_entity_decode
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method html_entity_decode....

```
    $file = 'wp.txt';
    $regex = '/<textarea name="example" id="newcontent">(.*?)<\/textarea>/s';
    if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) )
    echo html_entity_decode($list[0]);
    else
    print "Error";

    $file = 'wp.txt';
    file_put_contents($file, $list, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: I added echo html_entity_decode($list[0]); but the output in wp.txt is still full of &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the [html_entitiy_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function.